# Unsure how to resolve this overwriting error

Tags: python-3.x

I have a function that prompts the user to enter their firstname, Surname, Password and id.

What I realised is that every time I run this function it just overwrites my previous values for these 4 variables. What I want to achieve is to be able to run this function and then write the details to a text file and permanently save it and then be able to add another user's details and upload it. Currently when I restart the program and run my student registeration function it's just overwriting my previous variables. Perhaps I shouldn't store my data in variables?   Any tips on how to resolve this?

```
f = open("studentlogindetails.txt", "a+")
f.write("\n" + firstname + " " + surname + " " + universitypassword + " " + universityid)
f.close()
```

Comment: Will there be concurrent updates by several users?

Answer (score 1):

The `a+` mode is used to open a file to be read and appended to. Because it is intended to be read, the cursor is placed at the very beginning of the file under the assumption that you are going to immediately try to read from the file. When you try to write, the data written starts wherever the cursor is. You want to place the cursor at the end of the file before you write.

If you don't need to read information and only write, you can use the `a` mode instead, which opens the file for appending information and places the cursor at the end of the file.

Alternatively, you can manually move the cursor to the end of the file with the `f.seek` method.

The documentation states:

> fileObject.seek(offset[, whence])
>
> > **offset** − This is the position of the read/write pointer within the file.
> >
> > **whence** − This is optional and defaults to 0 which means absolute file positioning, other values are 1 which means seek relative to the current position and 2 means seek relative to the file's end.

So, if you want to keep using the `a+` mode, you have to remember to use `f.seek(0, 2)` to place the cursor 0 bytes from the end of the file before writing.

The available file-open modes and their use can be seen below:

> **`r`**: Opens the file in read-only mode. Starts reading from the beginning of the file and is the default mode for the open() function.
>
> **`rb`**: Opens the file as read-only in binary format. Places the cursor at the start of the file.
>
> **`r+`**: Opens a file for reading and writing. Places the cursor at the beginning of the file.
>
> **`w`**: Opens in write-only mode. Places the cursor at the beginning of the file. This will overwrite any existing file with the same name. It will create a new file if one with the same name doesn't exist.
>
> **`wb`**: Same behavior as `w`, except the file is opened in binary mode.
>
> **`w+`**: Opens a file for writing and reading. Replaces all content and creates the file if it doesn't exist. This mode is used when you need to write to an empty-file and potentially read from it later in your code (before closing).
>
> **`wb+`**: Same behavior as `w+` except the file is in binary mode.
>
> **`a`**: Opens a file for appending new information to it. The cursor is placed at the end of the file. A new file is created if one with the same name doesn't exist.
>
> **`ab`**: Same behavior as `a` except the file is in binary mode.
>
> **`a+`**: Opens a file for both appending and reading. The cursor is placed at the beginning of the file.
>
> **`ab+`**: Same as `a+` except the file is in binary mode.

Information for the modes was pulled and edited from [here](https://stackabuse.com/file-handling-in-python/).

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `with` keyword and write your data, you can pass the append argument as well.

```
with open("studentlogindetails.txt", "a") as f:
    # Using f-strings
    f.write(f"{firstname} {surname} {universitypassword} {universityid}")
```

Using `with` ensures all resources are cleaned up even if an error occurs.

**Note**: If this is just a project you're playing around with to learn how to write text files, then you're probably fine, however, if this is going to be used in production, it's best you use a proper database.

It looks like your writing some user data at a University, you can use the ID that is given to every student and employee as the primary key.

Also, **don't** store passwords in plain text, and **don't** implements your own hashing algorithm. Many robust solutions exist.

Comment: thanks for the advice guilty as charge I am a uni student. I did realise there's no way to save it unless i use a database.